# Why are these different way of declaring regular expressions not producing the same result?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's the code that declares the same pattern in two different ways

```
let reg = new RegExp("\d+"); // 1st way
let reg2 = /\d+/; // 2nd way
let string = "one two 100";
console.log(reg.test(string)); // false
console.log(reg2.test(string)); // true
```

I was reading the book "Eloquent JavaScript" and they said these two ways of declaring regex are equivalent but I don't know why the code above is producing different results.

Comment: `"\d+"` === `"d+"` ... because \d in a string is d

Comment: `new RegExp("\\d+")`

Comment: `console.log(reg, reg2)` to see what I mean